# IE8 absolute/relative positioned element doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a list (a `div`) with `inline-block` css position. Inside there is a `relative` positioned `ul` which is hidden. So I tried to convert this div into `absolute` by adding some class. Normally, when we click on the list, the list show up. It works in other browsers but **IE8/9**.

I google "ie absolute positioned element disappears" and tried their solution but no luck.

This is where you can do the tests : http://jautochecklist.googlecode.com/svn/doc/test_popup.html

You can save (Ctrl+S) the page and edit the script to test.

The conversion of position starts at line 956 (jAutochecklist.js). `wrapper` is the element I want to move

```
if (data.settings.absolutePosition){
            var offset = wrapper.offset();
            var dummy = $('<div></div>').attr('class', pluginName + '_dummy ' + pluginName + '_wrapper').width(wrapper.width()).height(wrapper.height());
            obj.after(dummy);
            //move the list so the absolute position can become effective
            wrapper.addClass(pluginName + '_absolute').appendTo('body').css({
                top: offset.top + 3,
                left: offset.left
            });
            elements.input.focus();
        }
```

Also, when we close the popup while the list is opened/focused, in IE, the list stays on the screen.

A fiddle : http://jsbin.com/anokod/1/edit

Comment: Just checking: Is `inline-bloc` just a typo? It should be `inline-block`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote `inline-bloc` in this post but it's actually `inline-block`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a fiddle. It requires jquery-ui/bootsrap/my plugin and lots of css/images. jsfiddle.net doesn't work in IE8 anyway

Comment: Well you had two issues in IE8, but you keep changing the page.  First, display:none wasn't being overridden in IE8 for the ul in which you create your dropdown, and secondly, you had a height:20px on the container, which was keeping the ul from showing.

Comment: Also, in firefox (probably all browsers), if you open the select box and the height of the browser changes, the dropdown becomes misplaced.

Comment: I use http://jsbin.com/ for working with IE. You still can't edit with IE, but you can save it and then view it in non-edit mode to see if the problem reproduces.

Comment: @RobertMcKee So what do you suggest? Note that the first list works but not for the second. Browser width/height change is not a problem, I can attach a resize event and refresh the position.

Comment: @PatrickM I added a fiddle, see if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the css style `filter` on the wrapper with absolute position.

In IE, when there is 2 properties `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient...` apply on the same positioned element, it will cause this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height: 20px in style jAutochecklist_wrapper

Comment: Nope. The height is necessary, it's there for a purpose. I fixed my problem anyway, thanks.